# How to create dynamic Buttons over dynamic ImageViews while maintaining the uniqueness

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uibutton

I am using PhotoScroller project and want to create buttons over imageViews programmatically. ImageView is a subView of ScrollerView. My code snippet is shown below:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; //initWithImage:image

//imageView.tag = i; // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial form
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]; //though it has no impact
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //to enable touch interaction with image

[self addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd] retain]; //Plus icon   button

btn.frame = CGRectMake(215, 550, 100, 100);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickHotSpotButton)           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //it wasnt working

[self addSubview:btn]; //Buttons are clickable but shows button on all images**

//[imageView addSubview:btn]; //Buttons are not clickable and are shown on all images
```

I have two choices rite now. Whether i make my button a subview of ImageView or ScrollView which is parent of ImageView. If i make button subview of Scrollview like [self addSubView:btn]; it displays at right position and is clickable but problem is that it is created on all images in the queue because i am making it a subview of parent view i.e scrollview. Else if i make it subview of child view i.e ImageView which is unique for every image, but still its shown on all images and its not clickable :/

Can any1 guide me on how to make it clickable and keeping the linkage between dynamic button and the image unique so that i have different buttons at various positions on each image in the queue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

wahib

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an extra UIView for containing both UIImageView and UIButton

```
UIView* imageContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1000,1000)] autorelease];
UIImageView* imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]; //though it has no impact
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //to enable touch interaction with image

[imageContainer addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd] retain]; //Plus icon   button

btn.frame = CGRectMake(215, 550, 100, 100);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickHotSpotButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //it wasnt working

[imageContainer addSubview:btn];
[self addSubview:imageContainer];
```

Caution with memory leak. You have lot of unused retain in your code.